# Alert filtered words using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xe2Zj/324/).

I have certain words which, when the user types them, it needs to be alerted to the user.
Right now when I type a certain line, for example, `I love ants` it alerts me the full line `I love ants`, but I want only `ants` to be alerted to me. (In my example ants is a word need to be filtered. Refer to the jsfiddle.)

```
var filter = ['ants', 'words'],
    reg = new RegExp("(" + filter.join("|") + ")", "g");

$('#texta').keyup(function(){
    $("#dest").html(
        $(this).val().replace(reg, "<mark>$1</mark>")    
    );
   if(reg.test($(this).val())==true)
   {
       alert($(this).val());
   }       
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding you.. *"it alerts me the full line I love ants but I want only ants to be alerted to me."*

Comment: Its alerting "ants" and "Words"

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript code to filter out common words in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686718/javascript-code-to-filter-out-common-words-in-a-string)

Comment: but it needs to alert once at a time,not the full line @PratikJoshi...then if i type something else,it goes on alerting me

Comment: @JoshC i will give an example...if i type `hello world` it doesnt alert,which is proper.then I type `hello world ants` then it alerted me but instead of alerting just `ants` it alerts me `hello world ants`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change it to show just the matched part using this:

```
alert($(this).val().match(reg));
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/fqthJ/1/).

If you want a separate alert for *each* match you will have to do a loop.

**EDIT:** [**Here's a version**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/fqthJ/7/) that alerts once each time the user types a word in the list.

**EDIT:** And [**here's a version**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/fqthJ/19/) that demonstrates the optional use of regexes instead of words. Note that any slashes must be double-escaped. So, for example,  to match `ants` but not `pants`, add `\\bants\\b` to the word list. As an example, this demo will match `\bb..\b` (so, `bar`, `baz`, etc., but not `batters`).

Comment: could u jsfiddle it for me if possible?

Comment: I just added a fiddle for you.

Comment: thnx for the answer..but everytime it alerts me once i type the word 'ants' which i dont want.only the first time i want that word to be alerted,i.e the word should be alerted once i type it ,thats it..not after that..is it possible like that?

Comment: @JoshC no man..this is the same thing that i had..it is alerting the full sentence once i have typed the censored word..Ed Cottrell answer is close that I have right now...just that it goes alerting me the filtered word again and again after it is typed

Comment: So, you want only one alert when it matches, then let the user keep typing, right?

Comment: @User211 exactly which - Josh's version, or my question?

Comment: @EdCottrell at you..exactly what u said i want

Comment: @JoshC it alerts me properly but if i type the same word again or the other filtered word,it doesnt alert me..

Comment: @User211 Pretty sure this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/fqthJ/2/

Comment: @EdCottrell thats exactly what i wanted...just add the jsfiddle to ur answer above...so that i can accept it as an answer..thnx

Comment: @User211 I didn't really help ;) I'm just sitting here trying to figure out and understand Ed's answer :)

Comment: @JoshC [I added some documentation to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/fqthJ/7/).

Comment: I don't have any experience with ckeditor, but it should work, as long as your script is hosted on the same domain as the page. It will be more complex because it uses iframes. For example, you can do something like this `$('iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame').contents().find("body").html()` to access the contents of the demo at http://ckeditor.com/demo. You just have to revise the script accordingly to access this content.

Comment: @EdCottrell hi again,just noticed,If i type plants  it matches which is wrong..what should i do?I read about some word boundaries but couldnt use it in my code..if u could help?

Comment: @User211 You can do that; you just have to use a regex in your word list, instead of a simple word. [**Here's a version**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/fqthJ/19/) that demonstrates the optional use of regexes instead of words. Note that any slashes must be double-escaped. So, for example,  to match `ants` but not `plants`, add `\\bants\\b` to the word list. As an example, this demo will match `\bb..\b` (so, `bar`, `baz`, etc., but not `batters`).

Comment: thnx alot for the help again..@EdCottrell

Comment: @EdCottrell 1 final question...i have modified my code a bit now...I am taking the words from a text file using the $.get function.For example `ants,words`.The code I have works,but when i type `pants` it doesnt work(i.e it alerts it due to the presence of `ants` in `pants`).How do i put \\b for this?this is part of  my code `var filter=new Array();$.get('1.txt', function(data) {     
    filter= data.split(',');`

rest of the code is same as yours..just that I want to add \\b,but i dont know where to put it..

Comment: +1 for alerting "due to the presence of `ants` in `pants`." :) When you do `filter= data.split(',');`, add this as the next line: `for(x in filter) filter[x] = "\\\\b"+filter[x]+"\\\\b";` That will add the word breaks to each term in your list. Alternatively, just put them in `1.txt` as `\\bants\\b,\\bwords\\b`, etc.

Comment: @EdCottrell its adding but to the words(i alerted filter and it showed me `\\bants\\b,\\bwords\\b`) but it isnt alerting..

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of the latest code or link to a demo?

Comment: @EdCottrell it doesnt work on jsfiddle coz it cant retrieve the file...if u using xamp or wamp u cud add a text file and try it...i am posting the code on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Mj4x8/3/ ..der is ckeditor also but for some reason it isnt loading...i guess u r interested in the script

Comment: @EdCottrell it worked..in your line of code `for(x in filter) filter[x] = "\\\\b"+filter[x]+"\\\\b";` i removed the two `\\` from the 4 u gave(`\\\\b`) i guess it was a mistake by u..thnx aagain...